# How to determine the model of a cheap headset?

Tags: headphones

I have a low-quality ($20-30) headset I use for recording. It's several years old but still works great... if it weren't for the ear pads. The foam pads are disintegrating.

Preventing that kind of degradation is something for another question, but my question here is much simpler:

How can I determine the model of headset I have? It has "Plantronics" molded into the rubber microphone arm, but I can't find a model number anywhere. Is there a good resource for finding out what headset model I have and how to get replacement foam ear pads?

Comment: Sorry, this community has the purpose to help with using the related hard- and software as stated in the FAQ. While your goal is trying to prevent the degradation it's unlikely that we can give an objective answer, and any answer would also apply on most non-audio-related products. As the Plantronics site is unlikely to still list it your best bet would be to either contact them with a picture, search for images of Plantronics headsets on a search engine or look around on the sites of second-hand sales companies. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @TomWij. I guess emailing Plantronics with a picture is the most likely solution to work. I've voted to close this question as off-topic, seconding your vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call Plantronics and explain your situation, they should help you.  I've dealt with them before and I haven't had any problems with them.